# Refresh HTML page without losing injected CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an iOS application (Status Board) that loads an HTML page from an URL, and then it injects its own CSS style into the page before displaying it in a sort of widget.

I have created an HTML page for that application which contains a script that shows a different text based on the time of the day. However, for doing so, the page content must refresh every minute and this causes it to lose the CSS styles injected by the app.

While I currently use either META Refresh or Javascript to automatically reload the page, someone suggested me to use XMLHttpRequest to automatically refresh the content every minute without reloading the page and – by consequence – without losing the injected CSS style.

However I have no great knowledge of web scripting, and I don't know where to start. What should I do, exactly? What files do I need to create, what code do I have to put in those files? A step-by-step guide would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: AJAX is useful if you're trying to gather data from the server that will need to be updated. If you just need to update it based on the time, then using a `setInterval()` call with the function that determines your outputted styles should net you the same result all without the HTML page being reloaded.

Comment: [Quick JsFiddle for Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/avrpmz7L/) in what I was talking about.

Comment: @Jhecht I added this javascript to the head of the HTML page `var interval = setInterval(function(){ $('div').toggleClass('even');},1000);` but the page doesn't refresh. Did I miss something?

Comment: I hope you remembered to modify it so that it was better suited to your needs. This was a basic example to show you the setInterval function and how it could be used.

Comment: @Jhecht The problem is that I don't know how to modify it so that it refreshes the page content... thank you very much

Comment: I've typed out a huge answer, but it won't let me submit it. Google AJAX tutorials. I know W3Schools has some, and there are plenty of them around the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No.  When a page loads, the CSS from the linked style pages is applied.  If you are injecting your CSS after the page already loads, it is only applicable in that instance of the page.

A better solution might be to inject a stylesheet into the HTML headers so your stylesheet is applied as the page is loaded.

Comment: That's probably the best idea. He would have to make sure his stylesheet is injected in the last position, otherwise the styles could all be overwritten.

Comment: I don't think that's how CSS works... It cascades by element/class, not by file order

Comment: I can actually confirm that's how it works. Recently I had to use JS to add in the bootstrap CSS to a webpage. If I added it last, it screwed up all the styles on the web page because it overwrote most the changes. If I added it first, only the class definitions for the buttons and such still worked, everything else looked the same.

Comment: I second @Jhecht, styles that are added last will override previous one. I do not know exactly the underlying logic/reason, but based on experience it is how css works.